# How to verify if a value is actually sent in a post request body?

Tags: c#, validation, post, asp.net-web-api

So I got a post request for a user to register everything works but in the post request I can leave out, lets say "Name" and "LastName" and it will still create the account in my DB but I want it to throw an error when one of the values specified isn't entered. Here is the code I currently have.

```
//Post api/Accounts/Register
    [HttpPost("Register")]
    public IActionResult Register([FromBody]User u, string name, string lastname, string birthday, string password, string gender, string streetname, string email, string housenumber, string addition, string postalcode, string city, string phonenumber)
    {
        var UserData = from user in _context.users
                       where (name == u.Name &&
                       lastname == u.LastName &&
                       birthday == u.Birthday &&
                       password == u.Password &&
                       gender == u.Gender &&
                       streetname == u.Street_Name &&
                       email == u.email &&
                       housenumber == u.House_Number &&
                       addition == u.Addition &&
                       postalcode == u.Postalcode &&
                       city == u.City &&
                       phonenumber == u.Telephone_Number)
                       select u;


        //Check for potential errors
        bool DupeMail = _context.users.Any(Dupe => Dupe.email == u.email);
        bool PhoneCheck = _context.users.Any(CheckPhone => CheckPhone.Telephone_Number == u.Telephone_Number);


        //Criteria check
        if (DupeMail)
        {
            return BadRequest("Email bestaat niet of is al in gebruik");
        }
        if (PhoneCheck)
        {
            return BadRequest("Telefoon nummer bestaat niet of is al in gebruik");
        }
        if (DupeMail == false && PhoneCheck == false)
        {
           if(ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        _context.users.Add(u);
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                        return Ok("Account Created");
                    } else {
                                var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
                                    .Where(y=>y.Count>0)
                                    .ToList();
                                    return BadRequest(errors);
                            }
        }
        else
        {
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
```

I Tried.

```
if(name == null)
   {
     return BadRequest("Please fill in everything");
   }
```

But when I do that I ALWAYS get send to return badrequest. I put this piece of code just beneath the select u;

Also when I Console.WriteLine(name); before the return BadRequest it doesn't print anything so I can't eval if(name == null) because it is always null but how do I check if everything that has been specified has been send or not then?

Any insights would be awesome, I can't figure out how to check if a value isn't passed through my body :(

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the value you receive is empty `String` instead of `null`.

You need to do something like this:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(u.name)) {
    return BadRequest("Please fill everything");
}
```

Comment: Was about to delete this question, it was simple, instead of If(name == null) i should've done if(u.Name == null) I thought I tried this already but i guess i had some other errors as well. Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 0):

in .NET Framework ver 2.0 , there is no 'String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace'.

so use this:

```
if (IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) return BadRequest("Please fill everything");

bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string txt)
{
    if (txt == null) return true;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Trim())) return true;
    return false;
}
```